# Write textfile and ignore HTML code

Tags: javascript, html

I have an app that will create a text file from a whole paragraph but I want to be able to add in custom text through a textarea or an input field.

But when i run the code, I got HTML code from the text area since its in the paragraph block, how can I only get the value from a text area to avoid printing the HTML code

This is what I get when I run and download the text file.

`Hello <textarea id="textbox">Type something here</textarea> Goodbye`

Here is my jsfiddle

Comment: You want to get the `value` from the `#textbox` node, not the `innerHTML` from the `#bos` node.

Comment: But I want the text from my paragraphs to show too

Comment: You are required to post your code here, not a third-party site that can change or disappear tomorrow. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just simple change innerHTML by textContent then replace the default textarea.
Hope that help :) Here is https://jsfiddle.net/lephuctai/nmtb4dau/4/

```
var create = document.getElementById('create'),
    textbx = document.getElementById("bos").textContent;

  create.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var text = document.getElementById('textbox').value;
    textbx = textbx.replace('Type something here', text);
    console.log(textbx);
    var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
    link.href = makeTextFile(textbx);
    link.style.display = 'block';
  }, false);
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i was looking for